# Creating email with filtered data from 2 sheets w/ VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with two sheets (sales and transactions).

The sales sheet has data starting in row 1 column 1. There are 4 columns and rows for each employee.  No employee occurs twice but Supervisor can.

| Supervisor | Email | Employee | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | 5 |
| Joe | joe's email | Dave | 6 |
| Joe | joe's email | John | 8 |
| Tom | tom's email | Jim | 4 |
| Tom | tom's email | Bob | 8 |
| Sally | sally's email | Tim | 9 |

The transactions sheet has has a data starting in row 1 column 1. There are 5 columns and rows for each transaction that week.  Not every employee or Supervisor from "sales" is in "transactions".  Some employees and supervisors occur more than once.

| Supervisor | Email | Employee | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | hat | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | ball | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | joe's email | John | sock | 2023.09.28 |
| Sally | sally's email | Tim | ball | 2023.09.28 |

I need to send an email to each supervisor on the Sales sheet with just their employee's information from each table each week. The number of rows are variable (i.e., there may be a more or less rows in either table each week).

Something like

Hi,

These are the transactions from the past week for your group:

| Supervisor | Employee | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Steve | hat | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | Steve | ball | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | John | sock | 2023.09.28 |

Below is the sales information for your group

| Supervisor | Employee | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Steve | 5 |
| Joe | Dave | 6 |
| Joe | John | 8 |

Tom would get a similar email but because no sales this week for Tom's group it would just be:

Hi

These are the transactions from the past week for your group:

Below is the sales information for your group

| Supervisor | Employee | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Jim | 4 |
| Tom | Bob | 8 |

I can't seem to get any of the vba on examples from Ron de Bruin to work.
The issues I'm having are

1. I'm getting all the data for sales not just that supervisors.
2. The formatting isn't right unless I go in and preformat the excel data as a Table.

Issue 2 isn't a major problem, it's #1 I need to figure out.

Below is what I get when I preformat as a Table:

Hi,

Below is the sales information for your group

| Supervisor | SupervisorEmail | Employee | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | hat | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | ball | 2023.09.28 |
| Joe | joe's email | John | sock | 2023.09.28 |
| Sally | sally's email | Tim | ball | 2023.09.28 |

These are the transactions from the past week for your group:
Below is the sales information for your group

| Supervisor | SupervisorEmail | Employee | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | joe's email | Steve | 5 |
| Joe | joe's email | Dave | 6 |
| Joe | joe's email | John | 8 |

My current code is:

```
Sub email_multi_range()

Dim outapp As Object
Dim outmail As Object

Dim ash As Worksheet
Dim cws As Worksheet
Dim RCount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer

Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

Set outapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)

Set rg1 = locate(1, 1, "Transactions")
Set rg2 = locate(1, 1, "Sales") 

str1 = "<Body Style = front-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
"Hello,<br>"
str2 = "<br>Thanks,<br>"


 'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set ash = Sheets("Sales")

    'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
    Set FilterRange = ash.Range("A1:L" & ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 2    'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=cws.Range("A1"), _
            CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    RCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If RCount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To RCount

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
            If cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

                With ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                  End With
                
                Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)

                On Error Resume Next
                With outmail
   
    .To = cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
    .Subject = "Low Docket Data"
    .Display
    .HTMLbody = str1 & RangetoHTML(rg1) & RangetoHTML(rg2) & str2 & .HTMLbody
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Set outmail = Nothing
  End If

            'Close AutoFilter
            ash.AutoFilterMode = False

        Next Rnum
    End If
Set outapp = Nothing

End Sub

Function locate(y1 As Long, x1 As Long, sh As String) As Range
Dim y2 As Long, x2 As Long
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh).Activate

y2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y1, x1).End(xlDown))) + y1 - 1
x2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y1, x1).End(xlToRight))) + x1 - 1

Set locate = Sheets(sh).Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y2, x2))

End Function
```

Comment: Hey Steve welcome to Stackoverflow :) There are quite a lot of things going on here, but I can only suggest a possible solution. The summay you need may be done easily using a pivot table. Now, using this pivot table, you may setup a template sheet to make it look how you want it to look (sometimes formatting a pivot table can be challenging). Once that is done, you may then use Ron's implemenation to send the email per supervisor using the sheet template where the summary is written.

Comment: You have `Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` but use `rg1` the unfiltered range in `RangetoHTML(rg1)`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'd like to know how to adjust the code so that the data from the first table is also filtered to just the recipient like the second table is.